# Prevent on the fly tag creation in a tag set

Tags: tags

If you create a tag set (not using main tag tree), it allows creating tags on the fly by end users.  In this case I have 3 tags and aded a 4th called 'D'.

[image]

[image]

> Docs:
>
> [Tag Sets] allow tags to be created on the fly without you having to
> access the Manage Tags page

In some cases, this is not a feature. We don't want users to make up tags - rather we want a pre-defined list. We do want the benefits that come with using a new tag set tree which via the docs are:

- they act as a "bucket" to allow you to group tags (i.e. an Issues
  People Care About tag set might contain the tags "affordable
  housing", "racial justice", or "water quality")
- adding them creates an additional search field in the Basic Criteria
  section of the Advanced Search

So it makes sense to use a new tag set when I have a distinct set of tags I want grouped together AND if this 'feature' could be prevented. How would you go about preventing having users add tags on the fly? Note: I do need users to interact directly with the tag tree not thru CiviRules, etc.